# arm cortex m4 xPSR change when branching

Tags: operating-system, arm, embedded

I am writing an operating system... I am working on context switching
..
I can switch the kernel into user program and go back. but SVC call seems not work well.

```
syscall:
    svc SYSCALL_SVC_NUMBER
    bx lr
```

when calling svc it trigger interrupt, I can see the control flow go back to kernel. The hard fault arise when it gets back to user program.

around here
--> bx lr

I've checked that all the registers are correctly loaded, except that xPSR lacks of thumb bit. That's why the hard fault comes.

But I have no idea why xPSR is clear to zero...

```
.global activate
activate:
/* save kernel state in ip register */
mrs ip, psr
push {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, ip, lr}

/* switch to process stack */
msr psp, r0

mov ip, #2
msr control, ip

ldr ip, [sp, #0x38]
msr psr_nzcvq, ip

/* load user state */
pop {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, lr}
add sp, #0x8
ldr ip, [sp, #-0x8]
/* this line can branch correctly */
bx ip
```

Comment: the input to activate function is the pointer to the top of user stack

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDBIBGJ.html
That document says that branching may clear T bit but why?

Comment: the document states what is well known BX, BLX and POP which by design drive the T bit can modify the T bit, because that is how it is designed.  If BX, BLX, or POP make the T bit zero then read three lines below:  Attempting to execute instructions when the T bit is 0 results in a fault or lockup.

Comment: I got it thanks,  Should I explicitly plus 1 when branching to even address??

Comment: bx, blx and pop are used to switch between arm mode (t bit = 0) and thumb mode (t bit = 1) and those instructions are implemented to make folks lives easier you just cant clear the bits.   so by changing stacks or by trying to do this context swtich you are perphaps not providing or preparing a thumb address but an arm address.

Comment: nope never plus one, OR one.  But ONLY when using BX, BLX, POP or when populating the vector table, in most cases if you use labels then you should never need to do this so if you find yourself orring an address with one to make it thumb, ask yourself why (one exception would be a bootloader want to download a program to say 0x20001000 and then run it in that case you would orr with one before the BX)

Comment: instead try to figure out why you are doing a bx lr with an even address in lr.

Comment: I traced my code and I found using svc instruction change xPSR from 0x01000000(16777216) to 0x100000b(16777227).

Comment: and it pushs even PC value onto the stack when entering svc exception

Comment: You are supposed to use one of the the special "exception return" values in `LR`, and return to thread mode via `bx lr` instruction. Requires you to setup the stack frame correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, yes, you are right, but you dont need to modify anything at the same time.

Using this code for example

```
mov r1,#0x22
mov r2,#0x33
mov r3,#0x44
mov r0,#0x55
mov r12,r0
mov r0,#0x66
mov r14,r0
mov r0,#0x11
svc #1
```

The stack looks like this when it hits the svc handler

Fairly certain this is documented

```
20000FD4 FFFFFFF9     return address                                                                        
20000FD8 00000011     r0                                                                        
20000FDC 00000022     r1                                                                        
20000FE0 00000033     r2                                                                        
20000FE4 00000044     r3                                                                        
20000FE8 00000055     r12                                                                        
20000FEC 00000066     r14                                                                        
20000FF0 0100009E     r15                                                                        
20000FF4 21000000     xPSR
```

On an exception on a cortex-m they behave in hardware in a way that can call a C function directly per their calling convention.  Understand that the program counter itself has an lsbit of 0, the lsbit of 1 thing is for BX, BLX and POP, it is used by those instructions to determine ARM or THUMB mode, the bit is stripped then used as the PC.

The return from an SVC can/should look like the above.  if you want to use svc or any other interrupt to do a context switch you need to build the stack to match.

there is a bit of a chicken and egg problem of course, for each thread you build a stack image like the above

```
20000FD4 FFFFFFF9                                                                             
20000FD8 00000011                                                                             
20000FDC 00000022                                                                             
20000FE0 00000033                                                                             
20000FE4 00000044                                                                             
20000FE8 00000055                                                                             
20000FEC 00000066                                                                             
20000FF0 01001234                                                                         
20000FF4 21000000
```

but you can put dont cares in the registers except for the pc which you set to the entry point of your thread.  with the lsbit not set.  Also you need some structure where you keep the state of the other registers.

then when you context switch you save the registers other than the above in a structure somewhere, which includes the sp, you then fill in those registers from the next thread including its sp.  then you bx lr to return.

there is a little more to it than that, see atomthreads or chibios or other open source, functional OS.

You are correct the address that was interrupted or in this case the address after the svc, the program counter, is on the stack without the lsbit set, but at the same time that is correct.  The actual lr used to return from the exception (svc or timer interrupt or whatever) is the [special "exception return" 0xFFFFFFxx](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100701/0200/The-EXC-RETURN-register) which has the lsbit set.

Comment: basically what Turbo J said in the comments.

Comment: I cant find it now but was pretty sure at least one of the cortex-ms the banked stack pointer was a configurable option.  dont see that now, the mpu is configurable so might have one without.  I messed with the banked stack pointer, found it to be more of a pain than it was worth, without protection it doesnt matter anyway, your svc handler could just use the main stack and/or you can just set a stack pointer when you enter for your own stack space and not have to mess with switching between

Comment: either way if this is simply a system call that you are returning to the application with then like any function call return with the stack and pointer the way you found it and it will just work.

Comment: I use svc and systick to do context switching. I build a fake stack frame on msp and change lr value to (0xFFFFFFFD). These steps can clear the interrupt state so that next interrupt can continue to arise and after bx lr sp still points to msp

Comment: I directly use even PC value the interrupt put on psp and bx to it. that's why T bit is clear

Comment: I guess you are not understanding what I am saying, you can just use the chip as designed.  If you are using bx with the real pc you are not using the chip as designed.  you are on your own.

Comment: I understand what I do is going against the chip design. I would like to know what is the correct way to clear the interrupt flag so that next interrupt can rise?

Comment: bx lr with an address that starts with 0xFFFF.... is what I am betting...

Comment: bx lr with 0xFFFFFFFx It's true. But I don't want to go back to user task. I want to clear interrupt flag and stay in msp at the same time

Comment: I really don't want to go against the design. My earlier code restore registers states and was able to switch between user and kernel perfectly. But it does not clear the interrupt flag.

Comment: reference: https://github.com/jserv/mini-arm-os/tree/master/06-Preemptive

Comment: I guess I know a way to deal with this. By raising pendsv in systick, so that systick interrupt can be raise next time..